# Using different connections with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My application pulls data from an external database and then stores in the application database after minor processing. How would I set-up the mappings for the external database since it's not tied to entities? This is what I currently have:

```
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    types:
                json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8

        rnr:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host2%"
            port:     "%database_port2%"
            dbname:   "%database_name2%"
            user:     "%database_user2%"
            password: "%database_password2%"
            charset:  UTF8

orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default 
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
        rnr:
            connection:       rnr
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
```

With this implementation, I get the error below:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'.
```

Here's how I implement the function:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $q = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $q->select('t')->from('AppBundle:TransactionSync', 't')->orderBy('t.id', 'DESC')->setMaxResults(1);
    $sync = $q->getQuery()->getResult();

    $em1 = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager('rnr');
    $conn = $em1->getConnection();
    $query = "SELECT id, merchant, client, phone, traderTransIdent AS member_id, transaction_id, transaction_type_id, value AS amount, points, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( transaction_date, '%d-%m-%Y' ), '%Y-%m-%d') AS transaction_date FROM merchant_transactions WHERE id > ". $sync->getId();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if(count($results) > 1)
    {
        $ts = new TransactionSync();
        $ts->setStartTime(new \DateTime());
        $id = 0;
        foreach($results as $result)
        {
            $transaction_type = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:TransactionType')->find($result['transaction_type_id']);
            $member = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member')->find($result['member_id']);

            $transaction = new Transaction();
            $transaction->setAmount($result['amount']);
            $transaction->setPoints($result['points']);
            $transaction->setClient($result['client']);
            $transaction->setPhone($result['phone']);
            $transaction->setTransactionId($result['transaction_id']);
            $transaction->setTransactionDate(new \DateTime($result['transaction_date']));
            $transaction->setTransactionType($transaction_type);
            $transaction->setMember($member);
            $em->persist($transaction);
            $id = $result['id'];
        }

        $ts->setLastId($id);
        $ts->setRecords(count($results));
        $ts->setEndTime(new \DateTime());
        $em->persist($ts);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $output->writeln($text);
}
```

Comment: Would this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html be eventually an option? You could generate the entities from the external database in your application. What I would really prefer is to have a REST API for the external database and consume it in your application, but this is probably out of your reach.

Comment: The Symfony2 Cookbook explains also the usage with two database connections: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html. This is possibly already known to you, but I put it here as an addition. Symfony2 has really good documentation.

Comment: I've seen both links and tried to implement, the problem is both connections are linked to Bundles while in my case, I just have database connections. I wouldn't want to create entities as I only need few fields from the table plus it's badly done eg. date fields in varchar etc.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give you any other advice, but using raw SQL queries. I hope someone more experienced with Symfony2 joins the discussion and offers help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot use `auto_mapping` with multiple connections and you cannot map the same Bundle and/or the same alias to different connections. Doctrine is probably looking for `AppBundle` entities in connection `default`, completely ignoring `rnr`; to check all entities known by Doctrine run:

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

and see if your classes are listed correctly.

To workaround your problem, you need to move the TransactionSync entity out of AppBundle. For example, you can create a 'ExtEntity' directory and change your configuration to something like this:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default 
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
        rnr:
            connection:       rnr
            mappings:
                ExtEntityMapping:
                    arbitrary_key:
                        type: xml # or annotation/yml
                        dir: %kernel.dir%/../src/AppBundle/ExtEntity
                        prefix: AppBundle\ExtEntity\
                        alias: ExtEntity
```

To avoid some headache, you can also use the method `Registry:: getEntityManagerForClass` to retrieve the proper `ObjectManager` for the object.

For example you can do the following in your code:

```
$registry = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
$transSyncManager = $registry->getEntityManagerForClass('ExtEntity:TransactionSync');
$transTypeManager = $registry->getEntityManagerForClass('AppBundle:TransactionType');
```

Going off-track, note that you are using prepared statement in a wrong way, which is prone to SQL-injection (maybe not if IDs are always generated by DBMS); use parameters like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, merchant, client, phone, traderTransIdent AS member_id, transaction_id, transaction_type_id, value AS amount, points, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( transaction_date, '%d-%m-%Y' ), '%Y-%m-%d') AS transaction_date FROM merchant_transactions WHERE id > :minId";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array('minId' => $sync->getId());
```

And even better -- if you can modify your database schema -- use DateTime for `transaction_date` column and avoid the string conversion madness. :)

Comment: Let me try this and let you know. The database schema with varchar for date is from the other end where I have no control hence the conversion, you can imagine my frustration!

Comment: Hey, rnr connection is the external database hence different settings meaning saving the 'ExtEntity:TransactionSync' will use rnr settings which is now the database on my end right?

Comment: TransactionSync is an Entity I have on my local database, therefore I will not be able to save onto it if I move it to rnr connection

Comment: That's a problem, since Doctrine require a strict relationship between the connection/table and the class. You need to define an adapter classes for each mapped class... maybe there are other solution, but not coming to mind right now :)

Comment: No problem, I used a PDO connection for the external database and fetched the data as objects. Thanks for your help